# How to add two different size array in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, arrays

I want to add two different size array with carry 
i.e.

```
   num1 = {1,1,9,9,9};
   num2 = {9,9,9,9};
   num1 + num2 = arraySum = {2,1,9,9,8}
```

Comment: what you want here ? sum of both array int ??

Comment: One way would be to coalesce both arrays to an integeral type (hint: each step is 10 * current + digit), perform the sum in integer arithmetic, then separate back into an array of digits (hint: use integer division by 10 and modulo 10).

Comment: Why do you use array? Exercise?

Comment: have u learned Matrix multiplication? if not go through it. you will get idea

Comment: Have u tried my code? Pls update.

Answer (score 0):

I would say to do the following:

1. Create an auxiliary array.
2. Loop through each array `num1` & `num2`, starting from the end of each one.
3. Calculate the remainder after division of the sum by 10 (i.e. (9+9)%10).
4. Update a "carry" variable for each loop iteration to add to the next sum if that's the case.

Comment: Missing point: {3}+{7}, you must be careful with the "length" of the auxiliary array.

Comment: The length of the aux array is the max(length(num1),length(num2)) + 1. Even if you end up with a 0 in the first position of the array you can easily manipulate the array to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for simple calculation

```
    NSArray *array1 = @[@"1",@"1",@"9",@"9",@"9"];
    NSArray *array2 = @[@"9",@"9",@"9",@"9"];

    NSString *numString = @"";
    for (int i = 0; i<array1.count; i++)
    {
        numString = [numString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array1 objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }
    int firstNum = [numString intValue];

    NSString *numString2 = @"";
    for (int i = 0; i<array2.count; i++)
    {
        numString2 = [numString2 stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array2 objectAtIndex:i]]];
    }
    int secondNum = [numString2 intValue];

    int finalResult = firstNum + secondNum;

    NSLog(@"%d",finalResult);
```

Comment: It's working for small numbers calculation but when we use two big numeric value, getting result in negative.
If  u can do any solution for big numbers please suggest.

Comment: for big numbers use NSInteger